# Creating class from xsd with many imports

Tags: xsd, xsd.exe

So I've ready alot of xsd documentation and similar questions but I've run into a problem: `The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.`

this is the command:

```
xsd BulkmailAnnouncement2.xsd Components1.xsd Components2.xsd Components3.xsd Components4.xsd Fields1.xsd ManufacturingComponents1.xsd ManufacturingComponents2.xsd Meta1.xsd QualifiedDataTypes.xsd UnqualifiedDataTypes.xsd CodeLists1.xsd CodeList_UnitCode_UNECE_7_04.xsd CodeList_MIMEMediaTypeCode_IANA_7_04.xsd CodeList_LanguageCode_ISO_7_04.xsd CodeList_CurrencyCode_ISO_7_04.xsd /c
```

How can I create a class if xsd cannot support the includes.

Answer (score 0):

Move files to another directory or rename folders / files in the current path.

The problem occurs because the full path to the file / files exceeds the allowed limit.

Quote from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation):

> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following
>   paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is MAX_PATH, which is
>   defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following
>   order: drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by
>   backslashes, and a terminating null character. For example, the
>   maximum path on drive D is "D:\some 256-character path string"
>   where "" represents the invisible terminating null character for
>   the current system codepage. (The characters < > are used here for
>   visual clarity and cannot be part of a valid path string.)